# how to create a multi-host k8s cluster using k3d

Tags: kubernetes, k3s, k3d

I have two mac mini computers and I'm trying to create a K8s cluster using k3d.  I can create a cluster on a single host very easily.  However, I'm having trouble finding any guidance on creating a cluster that has multiple hosts (machines).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, you want to create k8s cluster with k3d on multiple hosts.

But, based on the information, described on [k3d Issues page on GitHub](https://github.com/rancher/k3d/issues/408#issuecomment-733883237) (issue still open), this solution:

> with the current version of k3 is not officially "supported"

Thus, at the moment it looks like the only version with single host is possible within k3d.

Comment: Sad to hear, but definitely answers my question!  Thanks!